# Set currency format for Excel cell that is created with ExcelPackage

Tags: c#, excel, excelpackage

How can I set the currency format for an Excel cell that is created with [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/)?

```
worksheet.Cell(i, 7).Value = item.Price.ToString();
```

Answer (score 25):

ExcelPackage will read out the NumberFormats on cells. So you can just make a sample in Excel then read out the cells and see what the format is for things you want to do.

Here is an example of three different ways to format currencies. Note the last one "hardcodes" the $ character, which may not be a best practice.

```
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("testReport.xlsx")))
{
  ExcelWorksheet ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("worksheet");

  ws.Cells[1, 1, 3, 1].Value = 0d;
  ws.Cells[1, 2, 3, 2].Value = -14.957d;
  ws.Cells[1, 3, 3, 3].Value = 5000000.00d;
  ws.Cells[1, 4, 3, 4].Value = -50000000000.00d;
  ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, 4].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)";
  ws.Cells[2, 1, 2, 4].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00";
  ws.Cells[3, 1, 3, 4].Style.Numberformat.Format = "\"$\"#,##0.00;[Red]\"$\"#,##0.00";
  ws.Cells[1, 1, 3, 4].AutoFitColumns();

  excelPackage.Save();
}
```

Comment: There is a Cells property in the worksheet, please check your code again.

Comment: Just for anyone else, these formats will make sure the format dropdown in excel reads "Currency", "Number", etc. instead of "Custom"

Answer (score 10):

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = 1.50;
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "$0.00";
```

This will create $1.50 as a number in your speadsheet